# How to link to phone settings from react native app

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm creating an react-native app and I want to show and warning to user if their IOS version is **< 11.0**.

That works fine. I have something as follows:

[image]

What I want is to go the phone settings if they click on **Go to settings**.

The code for that is as follows:

```
Linking.canOpenURL('app-settings:').then(supported => {
    if (!supported) {
        console.log('Can\'t handle settings url');
    } else {
        return Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
    }
}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

Thus I try to do it with `Linking.openURL('app-settings:')`. But the problem is that that goes to the settings of my app, but I want to go to the `settings` index page or even better to `system upgrade` setting.

I need it only for IOS.

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can no longer do that. You could use the URL `App-Prefs:`, which does what you want, but that will cause your app to be rejected upon review, because it's considered non-public URL scheme.

The only URL allowed by Apple is the constant `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`, which takes you to your app's setting, not general settings of the device.